What causes shadows to be more saturated than the local color of the object?
I am a 2D artist who has recently been studying light and ray tracing to produce more realistic results. I have a general understanding of light now: specular, diffuse, bounce light, diffracted light, etc. But there has been one observable thing in both art and life I have yet to find an explanation for: why do the parts of an object in shadow appear to be a more saturated version of its local color?
I understand why they decrease in value (less light) and slightly shift in hue (due to kelvins, the color temp of light, and bounce light colors).
The only info on the internet I could find with my limited knowledge comes from a youtube comment I found in passing. They described it as light being multiplied by the same surface reflectance spectrum of a color every time it bounces, making that color more and more intense while reducing the others. This would be the case for the shadows of an internal crevice of something that is a single color. But what about objects in shadow which bounce more off of other surfaces than themselves? Are they still more saturated in shadow?


Are objects with more saturated shadows surrounded by an environment which will multiply and increase the local color? For instance, the white bounce light around the egg multiplies with the yellow in the shadowed part of the yolk, increasing the overall yellow light output.

How many times does this multiplication/ bouncing take place before it reaches our eyes?

In the case of the red ball, is that shadow less saturated because the bounce light from the environment contains less red light, causing it to decrease the amount of red light on each bounce?

Why do we only witness saturation increase in the shadows? Is it because colors multiplied in lighted areas are always overwhelmed by the light's colors? And do all objects experience this constant multiplication either emphasizing or diminishing their local color?

I've seen it said that shadows are the most saturated part of the object, but I've also seen is said that the transition from light to shadow is the most saturated part of the object. Is one truer than the other, or does it just depend?

If light is always multiplied when it bounces, does this partly account for the hue shift as well? (rather than just "adding" white light to yellow, it is multipied, as in the egg example)


I included the unmarked pictures of the ball and the egg in case anyone wants to help illustrate what's going on with ray tracing. I'd like to see as many bounces as possible, especially in the shadows, to really understand the path of the light.
If anyone has any insights or knows of any resources that address the saturation of shadows, I'd be grateful.

Are these photos or computer generated images?

I believe they are both photos, I just got them off of google search

You should give proper attribution for those source images, since you didn't create them.

Ok I found the red ball on pinterest: https://in.pinterest.com/pin/750834569159546684/

Still looking for the egg, I had it in my notes from a while back...

I'm afraid it's impossible to ask your question, but I can provide some facts which may help to understand the issue better.

With some exceptions (such as light diodes), the light has a continuous spectrum. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum . The three RGB components are only an approximation used to facilitate color reproduction by cameras and electronic displays.

HSV color space is just a transformation of RGB, made for computer reproduction, and not for precise scientific representation, neither it represents perceptual properties accurately. See e.g. this discussion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Disadvantages . Color temperature is another term used to describe only some general property of the continuous light spectrum.

Whenever light reflects off some surface, some of its spectral components are reflected, some absorbed, in various proportions.

The objects in your photo are illuminated by at least one direct light source. This light reflects of other objects in the room (which we may not see in the photos), and illuminates the objects we see. The reflected light may have different color spectrum. An extreme example would be placing a red sheet on the side opposite to the light. The "dark" side of your object will have red hue due to the reflection.

There might be other light sources, just weaker or more diffused, so less apparent. They may have different light spectrum than the main light.


To summarize, there are too many unknowns to understand what's going on in these photos, but also looking at HSV components might not be too meaningful.

Thank you for your input! It sounds like there isn't a concrete rule based in science that shadows always appear more saturated. I wish there were an easier way to conceptualize what is physically going on, but I agree that there could be other weaker light sources in the pictures I provided and errors with HSV color space that don't make them an accurate measure of shadow saturation. As an artist, I've somehow got to come up with a way to predict the color of shadowed areas, so I'll continue to try and get a grasp on it!

@TerraMiller There are other colour spaces which more closely correspond to human perception, eg CIELUV and CIELAB. Also see the relatively new OkLab, which is supported by CSS (& hence SVG).

Very interesting, I hadn't previously taken into account the digital limitations of color. It looks like we are working towards more accurate representations of the light, but we've got to find numerically sound ways to represent what's going on. Cool!
